# Javascript timeout

Tags: javascript

I am using one javascript confirm which will get called after 15 minutes repeatedly.If user selects none of the options in the confirm box
i will redirect him after waiting for 1 minute.How to achieve this? My code is like

```
    var timeout = 15*60000;

    setTimeout("timeoutConfirm();",timeout);
    function redirectToClose(){
        var action='Some Action';
        document.mainForm.action = action;
        document.mainForm.submit();
    }
    function timeoutConfirm(){
        if(confirm('Please click OK to continue working on this page')){
            setTimeout("timeoutConfirm();",timeout);
        }else{
            redirectToClose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are better off creating your own confirm dialog (as a overlay, for example).

This is because the `confirm` will halt all javascript on the page until the user clicks the dialog. You will not be able to redirect after a wait, as your code will not execute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Any suggestions on how to create my own confirm dialog?

Comment: @user461807 - Look at jQuery and the thickbox plugin. http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Comment: Thanks a lot but can i achieve this using javascript alone?

Comment: @user461807 - jQuery and its plugins _are_ javascript. You can spend lots of time replicating what they do (generating a div in js that is 100% height and width, attaching it to the page etc...). Why do you need to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: cause i am doing this for an old application.If I use jQuery i need to add the plugin for this purpose only.